Can YubiHSM 2 device supports multiple containers outside the device?
Setting:
We have two or more ubuntu docker containers running on a single host Ubuntu/MacOS computer.
We have attached YubiHSM to the host machine via USB.
Requirement:
We need to perform independent cryptographic operations via processes running on each of these docker containers.
These cryptographic operations shall use YubiHSM.
Question:
Is it possible for more than one docker container to use the single YubiHSM concurrently?
Is it possible for more than one docker container to use the single YubiHSM non-concurrently?
To do any of the above, do we need any synchronization mechanism?
Is there a minimum reproducible example that YubiCo can share with us, to demonstrate the above requirements?
Can it support multiple containers outside the device? if so how

Yes, you can use the YubiHSM from different containers when the YubiHSM is attached to the host (or any other remote system) provided you use the connector. The connector provides thread safety around it’s HSM by using a mutex to ensure a single access at a time.
Although each YubiHSM 2 device is capable of supporting up to 16 concurrent sessions, it is only able to execute operations across the sessions in a serial manner (i.e. the device is single threaded).
So yes, it is possible for more than one docker container to use the single YubiHSM both concurrently and non-concurrently, with the caveat that the connector is used and cryptographic operations running in containers cannot be executed concurrently (i.e. they will be blocked).
And no, to do any of the above, you do not need any synchronization mechanism, this is handled by the connector.
I don't understand the question "Can it support multiple containers outside the device?". Can you explain?
For a minimum reproducible example to demonstrate the above requirements, do the following:
Install the YubiHSM SDK on your host and run the connector:
yubihsm-connector  -d

Use the following Dockerfile to install the yubihsm-shell client on Ubuntu:
FROM ubuntu:22.04
COPY /yubihsm2-sdk/*.deb /opt
COPY session.sh /opt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget libpcsclite1 libcurl4 libusb-1.0-0 adduser libedit2 
RUN dpkg -i /opt/*.deb 

On your host, also download the Ubuntu version of the SDK:
wget https://developers.yubico.com/YubiHSM2/Releases/yubihsm2-sdk-2023-11-ubuntu2204-amd64.tar.gz
tar xzf yubihsm2-sdk-2023-11-ubuntu2204-amd64.tar.gz

Create a test client that will repeatedly perform cryptographic operations on the YubiHSM (generating RSA keys as an example):
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
  yubihsm-shell -C http://host.docker.internal:12345 -p password -a generate-asymmetric-key -A RSA248 -i $1
  yubihsm-shell -C http://host.docker.internal:12345 -p password -a delete-object --object-type=asymmetric-key -i $1 2>/dev/null
done

Make sure the script is executable:
chmod +x session.sh

Build the docker image:
docker build . -t hsmclient --platform linux/amd64

Now start two containers, running the test script:
docker run --rm -ti --name hsmc1 hsmclient /opt/session.sh 0xcafe

and
docker run --rm -ti --name hsmc2 hsmclient /opt/session.sh 0xbabe

You will see containers hsmc1 and hsmc2 taking turns in generating keys with key IDs 0xcafe and 0xbabe, respectively.
